# Dom of iFrame in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have successfully created the iFrame and show it in my browser. The source url is chrome-extension://{id/path}.

Now I wish to run a JavaScript file in the iFrame from background.js.

```js
chrome.tabs.query({
  active: true,
  currentWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
  container.push(url)

  chrome.storage.local.set({
    container: container
  }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
      file: 'panel/content.js'
    });

  });
});
```

I have used the above code to execute the content.js file but it only can get the dom of the browser but not the iFrame, how can I make the iFrame accessible?

Comment: Content scripts are only for web pages and frames, but your frame is a chrome-extension:// page so it can't run content scripts. Load the script in standard fashion in the html of that frame file e.g. `<script src=frame.js></script>`

Comment: Yup, that's what I had done and it works. But I need call the content.js again from background.js after some user action. This is the part I stuck

Comment: Use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or even the standard DOM BroadcastChannel.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will try the DOM BroadcastChannel later on.